Toggle measurements on/off when in Edit mode
Is there a way to toggle Measurements ON and ALSO have Edit mode ON after selecting an obj for editing?
I'm using the measurement option to create a number of measurement for what an objects dimensions should be, so it has multiple measurements based on side, top views, but as soon as I change to Edit mode to create/make/edit the obj to be built to those measurements, all the measurements turn off. Can I have/see both measurements and be able to edit at the same time on?

The rulers are part of the Annotations system. Look for it on the N panel, View tab, Annotations and click the eye icon by RulerData3D. This will make the ruler lines visible as blue lines if the measure tool is not selected.
